Enabling a pager for '/help' command in WeeChat
How can I use the '/help' command in WeeChat so a help page is displayed from the top and not jumps right ahead to the bottom? In terminals, we can use 'more'/'less' commands for this or use 'set pager=1' in the GRUB shell.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

When I type in e.g. '/help fset' in WeeChat's input bar, I start reading the help page for the 'fset' command from the bottom. So I always have to scroll up to the beginning. It's cumbersome.
